# How to change month name DatePicker (calendar)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker instance and I want to be able to change the month names. How would I go about this?

I have made an attempt but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My attempt:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            altField: "#alternate",
        });
    });

    $( ".selector" ).datepicker({
        monthNames: [ "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6",
                      "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12" ]
    });
    var monthNames = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "monthNames" );
    $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "monthNames", 
        [ "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", 
          "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12" ] );
</script>
```

Comment: You are initiating `datepicker` to `#datepicker` element, not to `.selector`. So replace `.selector` to `#datepicker`

Comment: `$( ".selector" )` is not in `document.ready`, so it might be that element doesn't exist at the code execution moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datePicker trigger function should be inside document.ready() and Change the `monthNames:` property by `monthNamesShort:`

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            altField: "#alternate",
        });

        $(".selector").datepicker({
            monthNamesShort: ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12"]
        });
        var monthNames = $(".selector").datepicker("option", "monthNames");
        $(".selector").datepicker("option", "monthNames", ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12"]);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: _must_ is not good word here, because if script is placed after selected elements in HTML, then it will work just fine without `document.ready`

Comment: @Regent i change it to should. What about the monthNamesShort property ?
I used one in my project and it works but monthNames does not show the result

Comment: I didn't work with `datepicker`, so all I can do here is to discuss jQuery's basics, such as `document.ready` :)